# Sakai2.8.2 Translation Issues

Tags: sakai

I am using Sakai2.8.2. I want to add Farsi(Persian) language in sakai Preference tool.

I have started converting properties file to unicodes. Translation is also done. But left navigation bar is coming in english only after I'll change the language in Preference tool. How do I translate Left Navigation links in Farsi(Persian)? Is there any file for this particular changes ?

Thanks,
Nirav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The translation for tool title and descriptions are in the config directory tools.properties files which is located in this directory in the latest version of Sakai.

https://source.sakaiproject.org/svn/config/trunk/localization/bundles/src/bundle/org/sakaiproject/localization/bundle/tool/

Sakai 2.8 had the same pattern for translation but it's recommended that you use a more updated version of Sakai. You'd have to rebuild this config project and redeploy an updated jar to have it pick up the translations.

Most of the translation for Sakai now is being done on crowdin at https://crowdin.net/project/sakai-cle

Answer (score 3):

You are best off asking on sakai-dev@collab.sakaiproject.org - however to answer your question, you need to translate tools.properties (which is in the config module).